# How to save image to pictures folder in android

Tags: android

I want to save image to Pictures folder in android. I do not have any external memory card attached.
Code:

```
String ImageDirectory = "QrCode";
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        public void saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap, String busNumber, String imageName, EditText imagePath) {
            String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "QRCode";
    
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    
                myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                File wallpaperDirectory = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),IMAGE_DIRECTORY+ "/" + busNumber );
                // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    
                if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
                    Log.d("dirrrrrr", "" + wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs());
                    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
                }
    
                try {
                    File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, imageName + ".jpeg");
                    imagePath.setText("Sandeep");
                    f.createNewFile();   //give read write permission
                    imagePath.setText("Chintu");
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                            new String[]{f.getPath()},
                            new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
                    imagePath.setText("f.getAbsolutePath()");
                    fo.close();
                    Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());
    
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), f.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //return f.getAbsolutePath();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    //imagePath.setText("Pintu");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

`imagePath.setText("Sandeep");` is executed. But `imagePath.setText("Chintu");` is not executed. So, it throws exception at `f.createNewFile();` catch block is executed and `imagePath.setText("Pintu");` is executed

manifestfile:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: `wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();` You are complaining that you cant create a file. But you are not checking if the directory is created. I think its not. Why are you trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wroing picture directory. The path of Picture directory:

```
File pictureDir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(pictureDir, "ImageName.jpg");
```

Comment: made the changes; but the same error. Do I have to add permissions to manifest.xml file; please read the edited post

Comment: Did you grant the permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` amd `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for the app?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> is already added to manifest.xml file; anything else required?

Comment: I get->W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Comment: You need to ask permission to the user to allow the app

Comment: yes you have to ask run-time permission for that

Comment: Sorry, the permissions is `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. And did you verify to ensure that permissions is already enabled? You can go to App Info -> Permissions -> Check if that permissions is actually enabled